# How to make sscanf force specific format?

Tags: c, format, scanf

I have the following format for representing a complex number: `#define FROM_CHAR_FORMAT "%lf,%lfi"`

and I have the following sscan command:

`int sscanfRetVal = sscanf(s, FROM_CHAR_FORMAT, &complexPtr->re, &complexPtr->im);`

Turns out that even if the string `s` contains something like "1,1" (without the i), sscanf extracts the doubles from it.

How can I force it to check there's an "i" at after the 2nd number?

Comment: With a `%c` which you check is `'i'`?

Comment: Isn't there a way to verify this char as if it was in the middle? Like the way sscanf checks for the `,` in the middle of the string?

Comment: Seeing as you would then want to check that `3` was returned by `scanf` the only extra work is to check if it is an `'i'`. Perhaps `if(sscanfRetVal == 3 && ch == 'i') { ... }`

Comment: If people put the imaginary before the real, you could use `"%lfi,%lf"` as the format, and if the `i` or `,` was missing, you'd get 1 value converted instead of 2.  You can't easily detect mismatches after the last conversion; there simply isn't a way for the `scanf()` family to report the problem directly.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Do you see a weakness with the [`"%lf ,%lfi %n"` approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41128289/2410359) for `sscanf()`?

Comment: @chux: No — it is just not a direct indication of the problem in my book (it is an indirect one).  It relies on the initialized value of `n` in your example code.  A direct indication would occur if the `%n` were counted as a conversion (but the standard says it isn't).  The format will allow spaces after the comma; there isn't a simple way to stop that — and it wasn't part of the question, AFAICT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple approach is to detect if scanning proceed that far with `"%n"`.

`"%n"` causes `sscanf()` to save the scan offset at that point in the scan - if it got that far.

```
#define FROM_CHAR_FORMAT "%lf,%lfi"

int n = -1;
sscanf(s, FROM_CHAR_FORMAT " %n", &complexPtr->re, &complexPtr->im, &n);
if (n >= 0 && s[n] == '\0') Success();
else Failure();
```

This code used `" %n"` rather than `"%n"`  to allow optional trailing white-space like `'\n'`.

Note: `"%n"` does not affect the return value from `sscanf()`.

Note: Consider `"%lf ,%lfi"` to allow white-space just before the `,`.

Can use multiple `"%n"`

```
int n1 = -1;
int n2 = -1;
sscanf(s, "%lf %n,%lfi %n", &complexPtr->re, &n1, &complexPtr->im, &n2);
if (n1 >= 0 && s[n1] == '\0') { complexPtr->im = 0.0; Success_Real(); }
else if (n2 >= 0 && s[n2] == '\0') Success_Complex();
else Failure();
```

Comment: Thanks! but this format wasn't chosen by me, it's a requirement.

Comment: @KobiT Expand on your [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41127862/how-to-make-sscanf-force-specific-format/41128289?noredirect=1#comment69460740_41128289).  How does `sscanf(s, FROM_CHAR_FORMAT " %n", &complexPtr->re, &complexPtr->im, &n);` not meet your need?

Comment: Probably it is (working on that right now). this comment was about your note :)

Comment: Why do you check if s[n] == "\0"? When I tested it, with `i` at the end or without, n was always 3, so you check s[3]. What am I missing?

Comment: Checking there was no redundant input, such as `"1.2,3.4ij"`.

Comment: but s[n] is the 3rd char of the string, isn't it? `,` in your example

Comment: @KobiT  With input like `"1.2,3.4ij"`, `n` is expected to have the value of 8 and `s[8] == 'j')`.  Since that is not the null character, it fails `s[n] == '\0'`, as it should.  `n` is the number of characters scanned, not the number of fields scanned.

Comment: When I run it with either `"1,1i"` or `"1,1"` n end up being 3. So for the invalid input I get the `Success()` and for valid the `Failure()`. Maybe it should be the other way around?

Comment: With for example `int n = -1, a = scanf("%lf,%lfi%n", &r, &i, &n);` the `n` remains as `-1` if you did not enter in the correct format.

Comment: Well, it doesn't.

Comment: I did not post that comment without testing it first.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the `i` at the end of the format. It works. Sorry for the trouble and thanks!